# Java - Extracting call number from a String. Regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex, parsing

### **Example inputs:**

`"Undergraduate CT275.P648 R53 2008"`,

`"Science Center QR. 123 G45 2001"`,

`"Grainger 134 P 123 1995"`.

I am trying to extract the call number from the input string by ignoring the library name. Except this is tricky as there are a large amount of libraries / different nicknames for libraries. For instance Undergraduate is sometimes considered UGL or Undergrad... Also, the call number can either start with a number, a letter, or a combination of the 2.

Is there an easy way to do this with regular expressions? I don't have much experience with regex but I heard it may be useful for something like this. Otherwise I might have to check the string against a list of all the libraries/nicknames which would be very tedious and time-consuming.

Comment: What is the expected output for the above strings?

Comment: There is an easy way to extract anything with a regular expression. `a list of all the libraries/nicknames` is a better approach to exclude libraries and is included as [part of the regex](http://www.regexformat.com/version_files/Rx5_ScrnSht01.jpg) in the form of a negative assertion.

Answer (score 0):

Some simple code that should get you close to where you want to be would be to simply EXTRACT the digits:

```
    String str1= "Undergraduate CT275.P648 R53 2008";
    String str2= "Science Center QR. 123 G45 2001";
    String str3= "Grainger 134 P 123 1995";

    str1 = str1.trim();
    str1 = str1.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z. ]+", "");
    str2 = str2.trim();
    str2 = str2.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z. ]+", "");
    str3 = str3.trim();
    str3 = str3.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z. ]+", "");

    System.out.println(str1);
    System.out.println(str2);
    System.out.println(str3);
```

output:

```
275648532008
123452001
1341231995
```

The alternative is simply to write a for loop to extract digits from the input.

As someone mentioned in a comment above if you knew what you were trying to extract (having a list of ALL prefixes UGL = Undergrad lab for example)  You would match on (UGL | GL | SL)(\d+) which would make 2 capture groups, the first capturing the letters in the first set of parenthesis (your prefix) and then the \d+ would match all numbers after that in a second capture group until a non digit character.

There's a lot of ways to skin this problem, but I think that you need to define it better before someone can help you.